# "No input file specified." (I am stupid and deleted a user)

Tags: linux, nginx, users

So I had a server (running several sites) hacked recently and a low level user account was spinning up lots of processes (sending spam) that were crashing the server repeatedly. Out of frustration, I deleted the user.

I immediately regretted it and started getting 500 errors on every site. I created another user with the same username and password and now I get

```
No input file specified.
```

On every page.

After some googling it looks like this may have to do with my chroot and PHP and nginx having different paths. I assume whatever path setup I had before I deleted the user was deleted with the user. Where would I look to try to fix this set-up?

Thanks so much. I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where would I look to try to fix this set-up?

At your backups.